# Split column data as a seprate column based on multiple conditions and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to split column data which is given below including query and values

```
create table dep (
    a1 varchar(17),
    a2 char(2),
    a3 varchar(50),
    a4 int,
    a5 int,
    a6 int, 
    a7 char(1)
)

insert into dep (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7) values(507,01,'abc1',30,1,2,1)
insert into dep (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7) values(507,02,'abc2',31,2,1,0)
insert into dep (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7) values(507,03,'abc3',32,1,6,1)
insert into dep (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7) values(507,04,'abc4',33,1,3,0)
insert into dep (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7) values(507,05,'abc5',34,2,4,1)
```

Need to split column a2 and its correspondence column a3, a4, a5. 
Output like below:

```
a1  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  c1    c2 c3  c4 c5  d1   d2 d3  d4  d5
507 abc 01  30  1   2   abc3  03 32  1  6   abc5 05 34  2   4
```

If a7 is 0 then it should skip that record.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? and do you mean Corresponding column rather that correspondence column? Also what happened to a2, a3, a4 etc?

Comment: Are you trying to transpose the subset of rows where a7 != 0?

Comment: using sql server 2014,
a1 is main column and I need to split data based ona1, a2 and a7
assume if a2=01 and a7=1 then data should split for 01 like as I maintion with its correspondence column data from a4,a5,a6
column name b1,b2,c1,c2 is defined output column name
if a2=02 and a7=0 then data of shouldn't split  and it should check a2 and a7 value for next row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO; If I correctly understand your requirement; I think - as a static query - you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT a1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN a2 END) b1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN a3 END) b2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN a4 END) b3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN a5 END) b4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN a6 END) b5
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN a2 END) c1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN a3 END) c2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN a4 END) c3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN a5 END) c4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN a6 END) c5
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN a2 END) d1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN a3 END) d2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN a4 END) d3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN a5 END) d4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN a6 END) d5
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a2) as rn
    FROM dep
    WHERE a7 = 1) t
GROUP BY a1;
```

A solution for a dynamic SQL can be something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT a1';
SELECT
    @sql = @sql + ',MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' + CAST(rn as varchar(5)) + ' THEN a2 END) ' + CHAR(64 + rn) + '1' 
                + ',MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' + CAST(rn as varchar(5)) + ' THEN a3 END) ' + CHAR(64 + rn) + '1'
                + ',MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' + CAST(rn as varchar(5)) + ' THEN a4 END) ' + CHAR(64 + rn) + '1'
                + ',MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' + CAST(rn as varchar(5)) + ' THEN a5 END) ' + CHAR(64 + rn) + '1'
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a2) as rn
    FROM #dep
    WHERE a7 = 1) t;

SET @sql = @sql + 'FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a2) as rn FROM dep WHERE a7 = 1) t GROUP BY a1';
EXEC(@sql);
```

**Edit:** In your situation I think you can use a query like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT FamilyId', @maxDepe int;

SELECT @maxDepe = max(seq) 
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FamilyId ORDER BY MemberID) As seq
    FROM depe) dt;

WITH CTE(i) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i + 1
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE i < @maxDepe)
SELECT @sql = @sql +
    ',MAX(CASE WHEN seq = ' + CAST(i as varchar(3)) + ' THEN MemberName END) Dependent_' + CAST(i as varchar(3)) +
    ',MAX(CASE WHEN seq = ' + CAST(i as varchar(3)) + ' THEN Age END) Age_' + CAST(i as varchar(3)) + 
    ',MAX(CASE WHEN seq = ' + CAST(i as varchar(3)) + ' THEN Gender END) Gender_' + CAST(i as varchar(3)) +
    ',MAX(CASE WHEN seq = ' + CAST(i as varchar(3)) + ' THEN RelationCode END) RelationCode_' + CAST(i as varchar(3))
FROM CTE;

SELECT @sql = @sql + ' FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FamilyId ORDER BY MemberID) seq FROM depe) dt GROUP BY FamilyId';

EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: what if I had a2 value 1 to 16 and only a7 status can be 1 only for 5 based on grouping of a1 and a2 ?

Comment: I have rows in millions and a2 has only 16 unique value

Comment: SELECT URN
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN MemberID END) b1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN MemberName END) b2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Gender END) b3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Age END) b4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN RelationCode END) b5
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN MemberID END) c1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN MemberName END) c2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Gender END) c3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Age END) c4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN RelationCode END) c5
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN MemberID END) d1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN MemberName END) d2

Comment: , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Gender END) d3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Age END) d4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN RelationCode END) d5
 , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN MemberID END) e1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN MemberName END) e2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Gender END) e3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Age END) e4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN RelationCode END) e5
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN MemberID END) f1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN MemberName END) f2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN Gender END) f3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN Age END) f4

Comment: , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN RelationCode END) f5
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY memberid) as rn
    FROM Dependent
    WHERE Enrolled = '1') t
GROUP BY URN;

Comment: I'm using above query in actual data but getting result null in all column

Comment: I suggest you to add your real sample data with your real expected result instead of all ;).

Comment: shared data files and result in excel sheet

Comment: hi did u get any solution

Comment: I think you can use a stored procedure with my edited query ;).